# c# How to add Text into RectangleShape

Tags: c#, winforms, label, shapes

I'm trying to put a text like a Label into a `RectangleShape` in Winforms.

How can I do this?

Note: This should happen dyamically though this method: (this is all I have for now)

```
private RectangleShape drawRectangle(int x, int y)
{
    width = 200;
    height = 100;

    ShapeContainer shape = new ShapeContainer();
    RectangleShape rectangle = new RectangleShape(x, y, width, height);
    shape.Parent = panel;
    rectangle.Parent = shape;

    return rectangle;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a Label?? Using Visual Basic PowerPack components seems like a doubious idea, at best..

Answer (score 2):

You can find it here:
[Text inside Rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baw6k39s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I really want to use RectangleShape because there will be Mouse Events added. Another reason for using RectangleShape is the following: when I use the regular Rectangle or RectangleF, the rectangle will be removed as soon as I change the size of the window. And in your link I've just seen description for the normal rectangle, not RectangleShape. However thanks.